# How to add visjs events in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, vis.js

In [visjs doc](http://visjs.org/docs/network/) there is a `stabilizationProgress` event which I need to enable in my angularjs project. I have created a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LQidVPnOSLhyydsoTwD?p=preview) for the same.

I tried something like below, but not sure how to add a progress bar using angularjs. Here is a [link to give an idea](http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/loadingBar.html)

```
<vis-network data="data" options="options" events="events"></vis-network>
```

Controller code

```
$scope.events = [{
    stabilizationProgress: function (obj) {

    },
    stabilizationIterationsDone: function () {

    }
}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable a `directive` that will transport the data between `angular` and `vis`. Every characteristic of `vis` can be mimified on `angular`, integrating `vis` to its `$digest` cycle.

Directives are to deal with `DOM manipulation` and integration with third party plugins like `vis`.

For example, if you want to get something updated when `vis` tells something, you can achieve like the below (supposing that `vis.event()` is a real method from `vis` API):

```
/* On directive's link() function */

vis.event('bla-bla-bla', function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    scope.$evalAsync(function () {
        scope.emit('vis:bla-bla-bla', arg1, arg2, arg3);
    });
});
```

On your controller, you can listen to this event:

```
// On a parent controller where the directive is placed
//
// The $scope below can be $scope too,
// but it will traverse all child scopes first
$scope.$on('vis:bla-bla-bla', function ($event, arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    $event.stopPropagation(); // Useful, to avoid performance leak

    console.log($event, arg1, arg2, arg3);
});
```

## Edit 1:

I've read a bit of the Plunkr that you pointed out:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XlRkfazfYBmj0GM1PTeC?p=info

The events system is already there, you were missing the attribute on the `vis-network` element, the `events` one, with the events wanted binded to it.

I suggest to you to comment out some of them and uncomment one each time to see it working. At the moment, they are all active and logging on console!

Comment: Can you please help me with it in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LQidVPnOSLhyydsoTwD?p=preview)?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller  you define a callback method that should be executed when the event is fired e.g.:

```
function actOnEvent($event){
     window.alert($event. ...);
};
```

$event is the populated event with all info you need.
Then still in your controller you need to map the event to your function e.g.:

```
var vm = this;
vm.events = { click: actOnEvent};
```

and in your html template you have e.g.

```
<vis-network data="vm.data" options="vm.options" events="vm.events"></vis-network>
```